# little help in drawing a simple figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

I am a noob in latex, and I received a lot from you.
Is there any chance someone can help me with this figure, I am totally stuck.

[image]

So far I could only do this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[name=plot, 
    xmin=0, 
    xmax=20, 
    ymin=0,
    ymax=20,
    yticklabels={,,}, 
    xticklabels={,,},  
    ytick=\empty, 
    xtick=\empty, 
    axis line style={draw=none},
    tick style={draw=none}
    ]
    
    \addplot[black,mark=.] {1*x};
    \addplot[black,mark=.] {4*x};
    \addplot[black,dashed] {5*x-5};
    
    
    
    \coordinate (A) at (5,1.25);
    \coordinate (B) at (1.25,1.25);
    \coordinate (C) at (5,20);
    
    
    \draw[<->] (A) -- (C);
    \draw[<->] (B) -- (A);
    
    
    
    \end{axis}
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{\textit{Plot name}}
  \label{fig:plot_tag}
\end{figure}



\end{document}
```

I don't why it doesn't display the vertical lines after I define the coordinates:

```
\draw[<->] (A) -- (C);
\draw[<->] (B) -- (A);
```

Comment: take also a look [here](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html) for a nice visual approach of what pgf can do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start. Some remarks:

- For some of the features used below the compatibility setting must be used, i.e., `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}`. You can adjust the version number to your own version of `pgfplots` if you want.
- To get the axis lines correct the limits of the plot have been adjusted to include some negative values (`xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax`), the axis lines have been set to the origin with `axis lines=middle` and the axes have been made visible by commenting out the `draw=none` option.
- The axis labels are printed differently with `axis lines=middle`. To restore the regular position you can use `ylabel near ticks` and `xlabel near ticks`. However, this did not result in very nice positioning, therefore in the code below a more or less manual placement is done using `at`. The `cs` coordinates are between 0 and 1 for the start and end of the axis respectively. The `anchor` setting specifies the relative position of the label with respect to the specified coordinate.
- For the plots a domain is specified to show only the relevant part of the plot.
- The plots are labeled using a `node` in the `addplot` command. The position of the node is between 0 and 1, for the beginning and end of the range. The nodes are rotated manually, I'm not sure how to align them with the plot automatically.
- A pseudo-plot is added for the dashed line between 1 and 5.
- Labels on the arrows are added using `node` specifications in the `draw` statements, with some positioning options.
- I shortened the labels a bit to fit better when `\scriptsize` is used as font size. Alternatively you could consider `\tiny` as size, or move the labels further away to a position with more space.
- Final remark: although some `pgfplots` features are used, a lot of customization was needed, and it is not a 'real' plot with ticks and a continuous function. So for similar plots it might be better to use only TikZ and draw everything as lines manually, this will make customization easier.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,quotes,angles}
\usepgflibrary{arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[name=plot, 
xmin=-2, 
xmax=15, 
ymin=-6,
ymax=23,
%yticklabels={,,}, 
%xticklabels={,,},  
ytick=\empty, 
xtick=\empty, 
%axis line style={draw=none},
axis lines=middle,
xlabel={Air Mass flow},
ylabel={Compression Ratio},
%ylabel near ticks, % automatic placement, not used here
%xlabel near ticks, % 
x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.9,0.2)},anchor=north east},
y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.1,0.7)},rotate=90,anchor=south},
tick style={draw=none}
]

\addplot[black,mark=.,domain=0:10] {1*x} node[pos=0.8,above,rotate=25] {\scriptsize surge line 1};
\addplot[black,mark=.,domain=0:6] {4*x} node[pos=0.8,above,rotate=60] {\scriptsize surge line 2};
\addplot[black,dashed,domain=0:5] {5*x-5};
\addplot[black,dashed,domain=1:5] {1};

\coordinate (A) at (5,1.25);
\coordinate (B) at (1.25,1.25);
\coordinate (A1) at (5,-1.25);
\coordinate (B1) at (1.25,-1.25);
\coordinate (C) at (5,20);
  
\draw[<->] (A) -- (C) node[near start,rotate=90,anchor=north,xshift=8mm] {\scriptsize compression ratio increase};
\draw[<->] (A1) -- (B1) node[midway,anchor=north] {\scriptsize air mass increase};
\draw[densely dotted] (A) -- (A1);
\draw[densely dotted] (B) -- (B1);

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Slightly simplified your sketch, removed are all duplicate libraries, considered that `pgfplots` load `tikz`, and `hyperref` load `\url` package. For shorter image code are defined two styles for nodes on lines and for arrows used in the measuring of distances.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\fancyhead[]{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\parindent 0ex

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}   % 1.17 is recent at time of writing answer
\usepgfplotslibrary{groupplots}
\usetikzlibrary{angles, arrows.meta,
                calc,
                quotes,}
\usepackage{hyperref} % it load url too

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    lbl/.style = {inner ysep=2pt, font=\scriptsize, text=black,
                  align=center, anchor=south east, rotate=#1},
    arr/.style = {{Bar[width=3.2mm].Straight Barb[]}-{Straight Barb[].Bar[width=3.2mm]},
                  transform canvas={#1}}
                        ]
\begin{axis}[name=plot,
    xmin=-1,    xmax=15,
    ymin=-6,    ymax=25,
    xtick=\empty,   
    ytick=\empty,
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel={Air Mass flow},
    ylabel={Compression Ratio},
    x label style={anchor=north east},
    y label style={rotate=90,anchor=south east},
    samples=2
    ]

\addplot[gray,domain=0:12] {x}   node[lbl=25] {surge line 1};
\addplot[gray,domain=0:6]  {4*x} node[lbl=60] {surge line 2};
%
\addplot[dashed,domain=0:5] {5*x-5};

\coordinate (A) at (1.25,1.25);
\coordinate (B) at (5,1.25);
\coordinate (C) at (5,20);

\coordinate (A1) at (5,-1.25);
\coordinate (B1) at (1.25,-1.25);

\draw[arr={yshift=-5mm}] (A) -- node[lbl=0, below] {air mass\\ increase} (B) ;
\draw[arr={xshift= 3mm}] (B) -- node[lbl=90, below] {compression\\ ratio increase} (C);
\draw[densely dotted, red] (A) -| (C);

\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My solution without `pgfplots`

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=5pt,font=\Huge,
ds-1/.style={dash pattern=on 20pt off 10pt},
ds-2/.style={dash pattern=on 30pt off 10pt}]

\draw[-{Triangle[open]},name path=xa] (-4.5,0) -- (29.5,0) 
   node[below,very near end]{Air Mass Flow}; %x axis
\draw[-{Triangle[open]},name path=ya] (0,-5.5) -- (0,28)     
   node[sloped,above,pos=0.85]{Compression Ratio}; %y axis

\draw[domain=0:20,name path=sl1] plot (\x,1.175*\x)
   node[sloped,above left,rotate=atan(1.175)]{surge line 1};
\draw[domain=0:11.5,name path=sl2] plot (\x,2.304*\x) 
   node[sloped,above left,rotate=atan(2.304),font=\Huge]{surge line 2};

\path[domain=-1:11.5,name path=dl] plot (\x,2.791*\x -4.209);
\fill[name intersections={of=sl1 and dl, by=p1},
       name intersections={of=sl2 and dl, by=p2},
       name intersections={of=dl and ya, by=py}](p1) circle[radius=8pt] (p2) circle[radius=8pt];
\draw[dashed,ds-2] (p2) -- (py);  
\draw[dashed,ds-1] (p1) -- ([xshift=15mm]p2 |- p1) coordinate(p1s) (p2) -- (p1s |- p2);
\draw[{Triangle[]}-{Triangle[]}] (p1s) -- (p1s |- p2)
   node[midway,below,sloped]{improvement in compression ratio};
\draw[dashed,ds-1] (p1) -- +(0,-15mm) coordinate(p1b) (p2) -- (p1b -| p2);
\draw[{Triangle[]}-{Triangle[]}] (p1b) -- (p1b -| p2) 
   node[right]{improvement in air mass};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]